# Passing variable to usercontrol with dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to pass parameter in my usercontrol with DependencyProperty.

This is my main view :

```
<control:HeaderControl TestText="test" DataContext="{Binding HeaderViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" />
```

This is my code behind of my userControl :

```
public partial class Connexion : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Connexion()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TestTitleProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "TestText",
                typeof(string),
                typeof(Connexion),
                new PropertyMetadata(default(string), null));

        public string TestText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TestTitleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TestTitleProperty, value); }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        //this.DataContext = new ConnexionViewModel();
    }
```

And then, there is no data in my userControl..., my TextBlock is empty :

```
<TextBlock x:Name="headerTitle" Text="{Binding TestText}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="24" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Anyone have an idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Funny, you don't show us how you're trying to bind to the property in your view.  The one thing we needed to see.  If I had to guess... wait, I DO have to guess...  you need to add an x:Name to your UserControl element and use an ElementName binding to access it.

Comment: @S.Akbari Thanks but this is not the same problem...